# Show $\frac{1}{(2+jw)^2}*\frac{1}{4+jw} $ equal to $\frac{1}{4(4+jw)}-\frac{1}{4(2+jw)}+\frac{1}{2(2+jw)^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show $\frac{1}{(2+jw)^2}*\frac{1}{4+jw} $
equal to $\frac{1}{4(4+jw)}-\frac{1}{4(2+jw)}+\frac{1}{2(2+jw)^2}$

No idea to do it.Please give hint.

Comment: Your expression seems trivially not true!

Comment: I think you shold check the expression or give more context about that.

Comment: @gimusi sorry, already revised.

Comment: @Michael Now the question in the question, and the question in the question are different.

Comment: Let $$\frac{1}{(2+jw)^2}*\frac{1}{4+jw} = \frac{A}{4+jw}+\frac{B}{2+jw}+\frac{C}{(2+jw)^2}$$
and find $A,B,C$.

Comment: @Nosrati I think that is wt i want.I forget the name of that property. Wt's it call? Thanks.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition examples

Answer (score 0):

Just check it

$$\frac{1}{4(4+jw)}-\frac{1}{4(2+jw)}+\frac{1}{2(2+jw)^2}=\frac{(2+jw)^2-(4+jw)(2+jw)+2(4+jw)}{4(4+jw)(2+jw)^2}=\ldots$$